# Upserting Person Accounts using External IDs in Contact object

Tags: rest-api, upsert, person-accounts

I am trying to upsert a record in Salesforce using the REST API.

My endpoint looks something like this

```
https://demoaccount--dev.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/Profile_UUID__pc/112233
```

The payload looks like this:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Doe",    
    "RecordTypeId" : "0120C0000006eySWER",
    "Profile_UUID__pc" : "112233",
    "Email" : "john.doe@mail.com"
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to upsert using the `Profile_UUID__pc` which is a field in my Contact object that can be accessed using `__pc` affix. Despite `Contact.Profile_UUID__c` being set as an External ID, and it being accessible to all profiles I cant upsert using it.

I get the following error:

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "Provided external ID field does not exist or is not accessible: Profile_UUID__pc"
    }
]
```

When I describe the Account object I can see that field is definitely available, but interestingly it shows `"externalId": false` in the field schema.

Can we not upsert using fields from the Contact object in Accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upsert on the Account object using an External Key from the Contact object. I've had to move the fields into the Account object instead.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can directly pass the external Id in the payload. Try something like this:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Doe",    
    "RecordTypeId" : "0120C0000006eySWER",
    "Contacts" : {"Profile_UUID__pc" : "112233"},
    "Email" : "john.doe@mail.com"
}
```

Comment: The payload above would be correct if I were trying to link to a Contact record using the Contact field lookup.

Comment: I'm not sure if you figured this out already but here is some insight from Salesforce. hope this helps

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4RfAAK&title=non-view-all-data-users-cannot-get-a-record-through-a-rest-external-id-resource-if-the-exernal-id-is-not-unique